# How can I save yahooquery results including dates?

Tags: python, download, yahoo, yahoo-finance

I am using yahooquery to download historical data for APPL

When I print the results I can see there is the Date alongside the price. However when I download the result in a csv file the date is no longer available.

As I would need to also have the date for the price I am wondering if I am doing anything wrong and if so how can I fix it

```
from yahooquery import Ticker
import numpy as np

aapl = Ticker('APPL')

price = aapl.history(period='max')

np.savetxt('C:\APPL.csv', price)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yahooquery uses multiple index, so you should reset it to single index.
Use

```
price = price.reset_index(level=[0,1])
```

This will tranform the symbol column into index and the date column into first column